# Warum wird ein Schuh daraus?

Tags: etymology, phrase

Wenn man Fragmente eines Ganzen hat, aber nicht weiß, wie sie zusammenzufügen sind, und dann von außen der entscheidende Geistesblitz kommt, sagt man (oder sage ich):

> Ach, *so* wird ein Schuh daraus.

Nun, ich habe diese Redewendung heute benutzt und mein Gegenüber hat sie nicht gekannt. Verdutzte Blicke, wo denn hier plötzlich ein Schuh herkäme. Nun ja, woher eigentlich? Warum werden Schuhe daraus, nicht Socken, Hüte, Mäntel, Schachteln?

---

Als Zusatzfrage: Ist die Redewendung im gesamten deutschen Sprachraum bekannt?

(Ich würde anregen, dass *eine* Community-Wiki-Antwort mit diesem Inhalt erstellt wird, in die sich jeder eintragen kann. Bitte diesen Aspekt nicht extra beantworten, es sei denn, es wird gleichzeitig die Hauptfrage beantwortet.)

Answer (score 12):

Im Duden Band 11 *Redewendungen* wird die umgangssprachliche Redewendung als **„umgekehrt wird ein Schuh draus“** aufgeführt.

> Ich soll dich angeschrien haben? Umgekehrt wird ein Schuh draus!
>
> Dafür benötigt er nicht das Vertrauen der Schauspieler. Eher umgekehrt wird da ein Schuh draus.

Als Erklärung wird angenommen, dass früher in der Schuhmacherei bei bestimmten Schuhen die Nähte zunächst auf der späteren Innenseite genäht wurden, sodass das Werkstück vor der Fertigstellung gewendet werden musste; dann konnte man die spätere Schuhform sehr viel deutlicher erkennen.

Answer (score 5):

Dem [Redensarten-Index](http://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=Andersrum%20wird%20ein%20Schuh%20draus&bool=relevanz&suchspalte%5B%5D=rart_ou) zur Folge geht es hier zurück auf

> Andersherum wird ein Schuh draus!

Diese widerum hat folgenden Ursprung:

> Früher war es bei der Herstellung von Schuhen üblich, die Nähte versteckt am Inneren des Rohschuhes anzubringen, so dass dieses nach außen gekehrt werden musste. Für den Lehrling mag so manches Mal die redensartlich gewordene Mahnung notwendig gewesen sein, den Schuh rechtzeitig umzustülpen.

Heute meist gängiger ist die Redewendung aber ohne "andersrum" und daher ist die Herkunft leicht verschleiert. Wohlbemerkt ist die Bedeutung dieser beiden Redewendungen leicht unterschiedlich.